# Getting user by name OR email with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I need to get inputs from a login form and search for a matching user without knowing if they chosed to login using their name or email.

```
async function getUser(req, res) {
    const { name="", email="", password } = req.body

    const user = 
        (await User.findAll({ where: {name, password} }))
        ||
        (await User.findAll({ where: {email, password} }))
        ||
        ""

    res.send(user)
}
```

I tried to do this but it doesn't work either:

```
    const { login, password } = req.body

    const user = await User.findAll({where: { 
       password,
       $or: [{name: login}, {email: login}]
    }})
```

Comment: Consider using only _one_ `User.findAll` with an ["or" condition](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.1.1/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) in it.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I managed to do it by importing Op from sequelize:

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize")

const { login, password } = req.body
    
const user = await User.findOne({
  where: { 
    password,
    [Op.or]: [
      {
        name: login
      }, {
        email: login
      }
    ]
  }
})
```